# Powershell - Add another object to a JSON with multiple sections?

Tags: json, powershell

I am extracting a JSON from a file using the following syntax:

`$json = Get-Content $jsonfile | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json`

This is what my JSON currently looks like:

```
{
    "Server":  {
                   "CustomModules":  [
                                         "@{Name=Test Server Module 1; Tag=Server; Action=Option I want; Image_Path=C:Temp; Admin_Only=false}",
                                         "@{Name=Test Server Module 2; Tag=Server; Action=Option I want; Image_Path=C:Temp/Downloads; Admin_Only=false}"
                                     ]
               },
    "Help Desk":  {
                      "CustomModules":  [
                                            "@{Name=Test Help Desk Module 1; Tag=HD; Action=Option I want; Image_Path=C:Temp; Admin_Only=false}",
                                            "@{Name=Test Help Desk Module 2; Tag=HD; Action=Option I want; Image_Path=C:Temp/Downloads; Admin_Only=true}"
                                        ]
                  }
}
```

How would I add another set of values under the Server 'CustomModules' so it looks like this?

```
    "Server":  {
                   "CustomModules":  [
                                         "@{Name=Test Server Module 1; Tag=Server; Action=Option I want; Image_Path=C:Temp; Admin_Only=false}",
                                         "@{Name=Test Server Module 2; Tag=Server; Action=Option I want; Image_Path=C:Temp/Downloads; Admin_Only=false}",
                                         "@{Name=Test Server Module 3; Tag=Server; Action=Option I want; Image_Path=C:/User/TestUser; Admin_Only=true}"
                                     ]
               },
    "Help Desk":  {
                      "CustomModules":  [
                                            "@{Name=Test Help Desk Module 1; Tag=HD; Action=Option I want; Image_Path=C:Temp; Admin_Only=false}",
                                            "@{Name=Test Help Desk Module 2; Tag=HD; Action=Option I want; Image_Path=C:Temp/Downloads; Admin_Only=true}"
                                        ]
                  }
}
```

I've tried Add-Member but it only adds to the current values already there.

Comment: Are you sure you want string representation of your objects like `@{Name=Test....}` ? You will need to parse them after, I would recommend you to export them as real Json representations of the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append objects into the array `CustomModules` array using this as an example:

```
$json = Get-Content path\to\json.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$json.Server.CustomModules = @(
    $json.Server.CustomModules
    ([pscustomobject]@{
        Name       = 'Test Server Module 3'
        Tag        = 'Server'
        Action     = 'Option I want'
        Image_Path = 'C:/User/TestUser'
        Admin_Only = $true
    })
)
$json | ConvertTo-Json
```

However, as recommended in comments, your arrays currently have string representations of PowerShell objects, most likely due to *serialization exceeded the default depth of 2*. So to avoid this, **because you will need to parse them later**, use `ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99` when exporting the initial Json.

Comment: Thank you so much, both, for this help! Works as I needed!